# Why doesn't the + regular expression quantifier (one or more) work when searching?

Tags: regular-expression, search

I have a file with the following lines:

```
a=117
a=100
a=101
```

When I try searching using `/a=10*`, it correctly matches all of those lines.

But when I try searching using `/a=10+`, it does not match any of those lines, even though it should match the last 2 lines.

Why doesn't the + regular expression quantifier work when searching?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Vim you need a backslash before the `+`. So the following works:

```
/a=10\+
```